# Laravel 5.3 Join table to Auth user class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

i'm working on a CRM that should work with multi languages

my users table looks like this:

**Users**

```
id
first_name
last_name
email
password
**language_id**
```

**Languages**

```
id
name
short_name //en,fr,ru etc
```

i'm trying to get the user's language short name when the user is login
i tried this:

Auth::user()->language()->short_name;
and also this
Auth::user()->language->short_name;

and it's not working,
i add this to the User model:

```
public function language()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Language');
}
```

and this part to the Language model:

```
public function user()
{
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `first()` method:

```
auth()->user()->language()->first()->short_name;
```